# WxPython 2.9 in Windows: button will not Enable()

Tags: wxpython

Can anyone tell me under what circumstances this would fail?

```
self.next_button.Enable( self.__next_enabled )
assert( self.next_button.Enabled == self.__next_enabled )
```

I know it's not a type problem -- `print self.next_button` gives `<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x90ea9c0>`. Inserting `self.next_button.Refresh()` doesn't help. Neither does a `wx.Yield()`. I also checked whether the button was frozen (just in case), but it isn't.

WxPython version is 2.9.4.0 on Windows 7. I don't seem to have this trouble on Ubuntu or Mac.

Actually, it's a little bit stranger even than this: The button seems to magically disable itself when I open a `wx.ProgressBar` in a different function call. The code here is trying to re-enable the button as a workaround to that. Again, the same code on Ubuntu and Mac never disables the button.

#### Update

I hacked my way around the problem like this:

```
def reset_button_states( self ):
    self.next_button.Enable( self.__next_enabled )
    if self.next_button.Enabled != self.__next_enabled:
        from threading import Timer
        Timer( 0.1, self.reset_button_states ).start()
```

I'm not sure exactly why this works when `wx.Yield` doesn't, but I'll take it for the time being. I'd still like to know why the `Enable` call could ever fail silently and why the button gets so strongly disabled in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your self.__next_enabled variable is sometimes set to False or 0 (zero). If so, then when you call your button's Enable function with False, it disables the button. It would help if you included a small runnable example.

Comment: If `self.__next_enabled` is `False`, then shouldn't the assertion still be true? I'm less worried about the state of the button here and more worried about why the button doesn't set its state to *whatever* value I send to `Enable()`. (And I've checked -- the variable is `True`.)